# How to obtain signatures?

Tags: eosjs, signing

I'm trying to send a transaction by using eos push_transaction, but I don't have signatures. I found some exaples, they have signatures like below, they start with SIG_K1_
I have a transaction object.  I need to sign it.

SIG_K1_....

How can I get signatures, I couldn't find an api on eosjs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to sign check the `sign(...)` eosjs method:

https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/API-Reference/classes/_eosjs_webauthn_sig_.webauthnsignatureprovider#sign